# unpack and patch source rpm (rpmbuild -bp) safely

Tags: rpm, source, rpmbuild

I want to unpack source RPM and apply patches to the upstream source.

What is *almost* OK for me is

```bsh
rpm -i mypkg-*.src.rpm
cd ~/rpmbuild
rpmbuild -bp SPECS/mypkg.spec
# frolic in BUILD/mypkg
```

My problem is that `rpm -i` always deploys the sources in ~/rpmbuild.  And since I want to do it in a middle of automated test (which is running under root), I'd rather do this at least in my own temporary tree.

I have tried `--prefix=mypath` with RPM, but it seems that RPM ignored that (*after* hassling me about the path being relative ... nice job ;)).

Other thing that came to my mind was creating a temporary user and `su` but that's ugly, adds overhead of creating/removing the user and is not non-intrusive anyway.

So what are my other, way better options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change the `topdir` value. There are two ways of doing it:

- Create a `~/.rpmmacros` file with the line `%_topdir /your/path`
- Invoke rpm (and rpmbuild) with `--define "_topdir /your/path"`